# selenium-maven-plugin

Tags: maven-2, selenium, maven-plugin

i'm trying to set up the selenium-maven-plugin and having some difficulties i hope somebody can help me. My configuration looks like this:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
      <goals>
    <goal>start-server</goal>
    <goal>selenese</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
    <background>true</background>
    <browser>*firefox</browser>
    <results>src/test/resources/selenium/result.html</results>
    <startURL>http://localhost/MyProject</startURL>
    <suite>src\test\resources\selenium\Testsuite.html</suite>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

I have cargo setup as well which works perfectly. However the start-server goal runs without problems but when maven tries to execute the selenium:selenese goal i get this exception: Could not find matching constructor for: org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer(java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Boolean, java.lang.Boolean)

An suggestions? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bug in selenium, which can be fixed by downloading a new version.